# What system tables get INSERTS when registering object with Oracle EGDB (ST_Geometry)?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, insert

In ArcGIS Desktop, I can register ST_Geometry objects with the geodatabase (Enterprise 10.7.1; Oracle 18c):

[Register with Geodatabase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/data-management-toolbox/register-with-geodatabase.htm)

> Register feature classes, tables, views, and raster layers that were
> created in the database using ArcGIS clients with the geodatabase.
> Once registered, information about the items—such as table and column
> names, spatial extent, and geometry type—is stored in the
> geodatabase's system tables, allowing these registered items to
> participate in geodatabase functionality.

---

It would be helpful to know what happens when I register an object with the geodatabase — for troubleshooting purposes.

- For example: Occasionally, GDB objects become orphaned; the database object has been deleted, but the **geo**database system records still persist (an *artifact* of the object shows up in ArcCatalog that can't be deleted via ArcCatalog).

---

It's my understanding that the action of registering an object with the geodatabase INSERTS records into system tables.

Question:

What system tables get the INSERTS?

- TABLE_REGISTRY
- ST_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS
- Other?

Note: my feature classes have domains, but not relationship classes.

Comment: While you tagged this with Oracle and ST_Geometry, these ought to be more prominent in the question, since the exact steps vary by RDBMS and geometry storage. You also probably should clarify whether Domains or Relationship Classes are involved.  And the answer is different for the now long unsupported 9.x geodatabase layout.

Comment: Relevant links: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/geodatabase-system-tables-oracle.htm https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/dataset-internal-tables.htm

Answer (score 2):

GDB_ITEMS,
TABLE_REGISTRY,
LAYERS,
COLUMN_REGISTRY,
GEOMETRY_COLUMNS,
ST_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS (if using ST_GEOMETRY storage type)